# Selenium Python: How to assign an action to an element that will appear after another element is selected

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to learn selenium in python. Everything was fine until I had issues like this.
I.E I have 2 element selections:

Balance Type Selection Element:

```
<select class="form-control " id="balance_type_id" name="balance_type_id">
    <option selected="" disabled="">-- Pilih --</option>
    <option value="1, Deposit">Deposit</option>    
    <option value="3, Pengembalian Dana">Pengembalian Dana</option>    
    <option value="4, Sharing Profit Proyek">Sharing Profit Proyek</option>    
</select>
```

Project Selection Element:

```
<select id="project_option_selection" class="form-control " name="project_id"></select>
```

So if I select the Pengembalian Dana selection, the Project Selection Element will show option element:

```
<select id="project_option_selection" class="form-control " name="project_id">
   <option selected="" disabled="">-- Pilih --</option>
   <option value="1">Project 1</option>
   <option value="2">Project 2"</option>
</select>
```

It always throws an error when the code to perform an action on this element. I've tried using explicit wait. But is there something wrong with the way I wear it? Is there any solution for me to be able to select action on Project Selection.
I tried to use expected condition `text_to_be_present_in_value`

```
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/cash-mutations/create/incoming-balance")

balance_type_selection = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="balance_type_id")
Select(balance_type_selection).select_by_visible_text("Pengembalian Dana")

try:
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_value((By.NAME, 'balance_type_id', "3")))
    print("Pendanaan Proyek is selected")
    # Select(driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="project_id")).select_by_value("1")
except:
    print('gagal')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no "value" of "Balance Type Selection Element" in your case, they are just options under a `<select>` tag.

So you never get any response by `wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_value((By.NAME, 'balance_type_id', "3")))`

Try this in your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/cash-mutations/create/incoming-balance")

balance_type_selection = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="balance_type_id")
Select(balance_type_selection).select_by_visible_text("Pengembalian Dana")

try:
    wait(driver, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="project_option_selection"]/option[1]')))
    print("Pendanaan Proyek is selected")
    # Select(driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="project_id")).select_by_value("1")
except:
    print('gagal')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem by doing this:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="balance_type_id"]/option[3]'), 'Pengembalian Dana'))
    Select(driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="project_id")).select_by_value("1")
except:
    print('gagal')
```

So the first thing I did was select the option tag for Pendanaan Proyek by using `text_to_be_present_in_element`. So I selected the option for Pendanaan Proyek by XPATH. If Pendanaan Proyek is selected, then do the next script to select the project.